# Why does `project()` affect CMake's opinion on `CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P`?

Tags: cmake, installation

For my CMake project I want to build both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of a library and install them in the correct place using CMake.

However, CMake does not install the libraries in the correct places even though I use the `GNUInstallDirs` module.

I've tracked the problem down to the fact that `project()` affects the size of void*, which seems very strange. (GNUInstallDirs uses `CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P).

With the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
if (CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
    message (STATUS "CMake think we are compiling for 64-bit")
else ()
    message (STATUS "CMake think we are compiling for something not 64-bit")
endif()
```

the result is "CMake think we are compiling for 64-bit".

However if I add

```
project(x)
```

at the end, CMake outputs "CMake think we are compiling for something not 64-bit".

What in `project()` is changing this, and how can I avoid that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call to `project()` initializes most of compiler-related stuff. Before that call almost every CMake command and even variables doesn't work as expected. However, CMake doesn't generate an error about that.

Documentation for variable [CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P.html) explicitely states, that its value is "determined by a try compile", so checking it before the `project()` call is useless: a compiler isn't set yet.

Correct usage would be:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project() # Initialize compiler-related stuff
if (CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
    message (STATUS "CMake think we are compiling for 64-bit")
else ()
    message (STATUS "CMake think we are compiling for something not 64-bit")
endif()
```

Comment: Interesting though that no `project()` gives correct answer but putting it late gives wrong answer. CMake (sigh)...

Comment: Welcome to the *undefined behavior* world! :) I agree, that in case of command-before-`project()` the behavior is really **undefined**.

Comment: There seems to be an important caveat here. Although the documentation states that `CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P` is determined by a "try compile", it seems that this compile does not use the `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`. Try with "-m32" and it will still say 8 (for 64 bit). Tested this on Ubuntu with CMake 3.5.2. But a `try_run` with a short program will use the `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` and return 4.

Comment: Its been a long time since your answer, but it doesn't seem like the requirement in the documentation is satisified. Is the value of` `CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P` valid without running `try_compile`? And following thorni56's answer, is the value from `CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P` reliable at all?

Comment: "Is the value of` `CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P` valid without running `try_compile`?" - Not sure what do you mean "without `try_compile`". This variable is set on `project()` call. The way how the value is determined is similar to `try_compile` command, but this is internal to CMake.